# \overstrike in ConTeXt, can it overstrike leaders?

Tags: context, leaders

I have the something similar to the following:

```
\setuppapersize[A6][A6]
\starttext
\overstrike{Hello\hfill world!} % Works OK

Hello\leaders\hbox{.}\hfill world! % Works OK, nothing special

\overstrike{Hello\leaders\hbox{.}\hfill world!} % Not quite right
\stoptext
```

And this produces the following output:

[image]

The problem is that I would like the overstrike to apply over the leaders as well. Is this possible?

Comment: Since there has been no response here, it may be better to ask this question on the context mailing list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Via Hans Hagen on the context mailing list).
Use `continue=all` parameter for `setupbar`:

```
\setupbar[overstrike][continue=all]
\setuppapersize[A6][A6]
\starttext
\overstrike{Hello\hfill world!} % Works OK

Hello\leaders\hbox{.}\hfill world! % Works OK, nothing special

\overstrike{Hello\leaders\hbox{.}\hfill world!} % Not quite right
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: I accepted your answer but I only just now had a chance to try and use it ... however, it's not working the same way as shown in your answer - I'm still not getting overstriked leaders. Any ideas? I'm using ConTeXt 2014.05.21 (shipped with Debian Jessie).

Comment: @dreamlax: You may need to update your ConTeXt distribution. [ConTeXt minimals/standalone](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Standalone) is an easy way to install the latest context alongside an existing distribution.